# simplest way to create an extension function using Jquery

Tags: jquery

What is the simplest way to create an extension function or method using Jquery. I am finding it really difficult to create my own property using Jquery.

```
e.g

$("#selector").myproperty({para1:val1});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to just create a plugin:

```
$.fn.myproperty = function ( opts ) {
    // within the plugin:
    // this === $('#selector')
    // opts.para1 === val1
};
```

when you invoke it using `$('#selector').myproperty({para1:val1})`